# How can I automatically start application at booting

Tags: qt, autostart

I'm using Qt.

I could not find the function or class to start application at booting time.

In windows, for example, add register to HKMU/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Run.

I wanna know the function/class like above example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [QSettings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html) in order to set a value at Windows Registry.

```
QSettings settings("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",
                    QSettings::NativeFormat);
```

and then use the setValue function.

However this will work only in Windows so it is better to use an #ifdef before calling it.

Comment: I already have tried to do using registry in windows.
But I want global function including all os

Comment: Unfortunately there is no global function. You have to do it yourself using #ifdefs for every platform you want to support. For Linux you have to create an entry file for your application in '$HOME/.config/autostart'. For MAC I have no idea...

Comment: This seems to work only of `QSettings`has not been used in application for other locations like when`QtCoreApplication::setOrganizationName` has not been called.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of is the [QtService framework](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2/service-frameworks.html). It is available for all the major platforms (look [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2/index.html)). It might not be exactly what you were looking for but it may help.

It is also important to mention that a Windows service has no direct access to the graphical interface. This means that if the application is graphical, you'll probably have to redesign it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such API in Qt, you have to search for 3rdparty library or write whole code on your own.